# convert data elements in data frame via long to wide format using Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have my df as below:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvuqO.png)

I want to convert into df2 as below:

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr9m1.png)

I have been trying with panda, but still not able to achieve my targeted aim.

This is my sample code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('PathV1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['source'])
df1[['target']] = pd.DataFrame(df1['source'].str.split(':').tolist())
df1['index'] = df1.index// 3
df2 = df1[['source', 'target', 'index']].pivot(columns='source', values='target', index='index')
```

Appreciate any suggestions from anyone.

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read about [how to format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First extract the values from your DataFrame that you want to transform:
`data = df2.loc[:, ["source", "target"]]`

Then flatten these into a single array:
`data = data.values.flatten()`

Now assemble them into a new DataFrame:
`new_df = pd.DataFrame(data).T`

Comment: Aww, thank heaps. May I ask what does pd.DataFrame(data).T do?

Comment: When you insert an array into a DataFrame, is is inserted as rows by default. the `.T` *transposes* the DataFrame, i.e. it flips the rows and columns